# Reading NMEA frames on i2c device?

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, nmea

I have a linux machine which is connected by I2C to a F9P Ublock GNSS device. I need to get the GGA frames and some custom Ublocks frames from I2C, do some calculations and forward them to UDP.

Is there any simple way to use any standard service/library to achieve this parsing of NMEA/GGA frames or should I implemented my custom code for reading and parsing?

I have done some research and I am now trying to use GPSD.

Comment: Do you already have the NMEA data and just need to *parse* it or are you having issues reading the serial data as well?

Comment: I am able to read the raw data from terminal and now I need to parse and forward it. I am trying to achieve a solution as simple as possible to avoid creating my custom parser.